# How can I promote a published article?

Tags: publications, research-process

My article was recently published after a long process of peer-review. I don't know how to introduce the new findings in mainstream science.

Can you advise me on the best way to promote my study?

Comment: *Not* by posting the link here, I am afraid. :) I have removed the link to try to make this a more general question applicable also to other users.

Comment: If is of interest for mainstream, normally it is spotted already by the journal that put emphasis on it. Of course, this doesn't suffice to send your paper really mainstream. For that, your institution might have a dedicated office or person. I main mainstream news. If you mean "mainstream science", basically it is done already by having it published. Try to go to conferences or politely send it to whom may be interested.

Comment: could try answering questions on a relevant stack-exchange (or similar forum)

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of options when it comes to promoting your work, both amongst fellow scientists and the general public.

The first and most obvious is giving talks about your work either within your own institution or at other universities. If you're really keen to do this, don't wait for an invitation to speak. It's ok to email the organiser of a department's seminar series and ask if they have any free slots in the next few months. Most seminar organisers I know are very grateful when someone volunteers to speak, as it makes their organisational job so much easier. One bonus of the pandemic is that everyone is giving talks online at the moment, so you can probably give more talks than usual and in locations that might normally be too expensive to travel to for one fifty minute seminar.

Related to this is speaking at conferences. The typical conference season is the summer, but again with everything being online at the moment, more and more conferences are happening at different times. Talking at an online conference is obviously not a good replica of meeting in person, where it's much easier to strike up casual conversation about your work in the queue for coffee, but it's better than nothing.

Furthermore, you can try using social media. In my field, it's quite common to write a Twitter thread explaining your results when you publish a new paper, so you could do something similar. This only works if most of your followers are fellow academics; if your only followers are friends from school or fellow football fans (for example), they may be less interested. Personally, I prefer to write a blog post about my work and then draw people's attention to the post on Twitter. A friend of mine makes Youtube videos. This is your chance to get creative!

Finally, if your work is sufficiently high-profile, you could get in touch with your university's press office and ask if they will write a press release for you. This is presumably a more difficult process to go through but is clearly an excellent way to promote your work to a much wider audience than just academics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is there evidence that any of these actually work?  There are some studies on social media use and it is quite weakly correlated with citations.  Of course citations are a bad metric.

Comment: Plus one for the possibility to present at normally geographically and budgetary inaccessible institutions.

Answer (score 3):

Are you at a university?  Some universities do press releases and other publicity for research results found by their faculty.  So find out what office at your university does this, and notify them.  At my university, the Dean would send us a request from time to time asking us to inform him of any research we may have done that should be publicized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to *politely* send copies of your work to others in the field, *v.g.* people you cited, collaborators or collegues.

Remember that whomever you send this to has probably not chosen to read your work so this must be done *extremely carefully* and by thinking through the message that will come with the copy,  else recipients will think you are pushy or self promoting.

Such emails should be selective as anything that looks like a mass email will immediately go to the delete folder.